# Best practice to keep a resource file while deploying an ASP.Net Core application on PCF?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to deploy a ASP.Net Core 2 Application on PCF. What is the best practice to keep the resource file so that any modifications won't require a re-deployment.

Should it be a .resx file or a .json file or database?

Answer (score 0):

Externalizing all configuration in a git repo. Integrate Spring Cloud Config in your application to read external configs using Steeltoe.

Please take a look at [Steeltoe](http://steeltoe.io/) project.